# Error inserting data to a database table com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException in java

Tags: mysql

Am trying to execute the code but i keep on getting an error. What could be the problem.The error is : com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key) VALUES('davis','0704254498','0704254498',now(),'Hope you had a lovely day,'' at line 1

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO  tWebServiceSms(username,mobile,sender_id,time_sent,message_payload,status,key)   VALUES(?,?,?,now(),?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setString(1, webServiceSmsOut.getUsername());
        stmt.setString(2, webServiceSmsOut.getMobile());
        stmt.setString(3, webServiceSmsOut.getSenderId());
        stmt.setString(4, webServiceSmsOut.getMessage());
        stmt.setInt(5, 0);
        stmt.setString(6, webServiceSmsOut.getKey());
        int affected = stmt.executeUpdate();
        return affected == 1;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(WebServiceSmsData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "null", e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(WebServiceSmsData.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `key` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. Either change the name or use backticks around it, `key`.

Answer (score 1):

The word `key` is a reserved word in mysql that is used to indicate an index. If you want to use it as an identifier name, then you need to enclose it by backticks (`)